# If I add a MicroSD card to my phone will everything be erased?

Tags: storage, micro-sd

I am waiting for a MicroSD card to come in the mail and was wondering if I should bother setting up my phone before I install it.

I'm not sure how WP8 will deal with the extra storage and suspect it would just reset the phone. Is that the case?

How does it work exactly? Is the storage extended seamlessly, or is everything consolidated and reformatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Windows Phone 8 it works like you expect. You can add and remove without reset the phone.

In Windows Phone 7 you really need to reset the phone and you want to remove you need to reset it again.

Comment: If you remove it, what happens to apps and data that are on the SD card in WP8?

Comment: As far as a know you can't install apps there. You only can use to store movies, music and photos.

Comment: I'm not aware of any WP7 device that supports SD cards?

Comment: Samsung Focus is a WP7 phone that has a micro SD card